# Office 365 - how to disable birthday calendar for user

Tags: outlook, calendar, office365, outlook-web-app

I would like to disable a birthday calendar for one of our users. I know, how to do it for myself (the user that is currently logged in), but how can I do it for another user? I am, obiously, an administrator of the environment. I tried to do it by delegating an access to her mailbox, but in the options, I access the ones that are regarding my account, not users. Do you have any advice, if this can be done "ninja style" (without bothering user at all)?

Answer (score 0):

I am looking for the same thing but have been told it does not "yet" exist.

Here is the uservoice to vote for this to happen:
https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/264636-general/suggestions/19769992-enable-disable-birthday-calendar-and-holidays-cale

---

My recommended **work-around** until that is done...
Ask the user:

> On this page:
> https://outlook.office365.com/mail/options/calendar/view/birthdayCalendar
>
> Please untick "Turn on the birthday calendar" and then choose "save"

(URL will need to be adjusted if you use on-prem email)

I agree that user-intervention is not ideal, but in this case it will be self-explanatory without the user needing to know which menu this option is hidden behind - they will just get taken straight to the right spot.

Enable SSO on their computer so they wont get asked for credentials when opening OWA.